# SlideShow com imagens a partir de URLs

Tags: java, android

Eu estava desenvolvendo uma *slideshow* carregando imagens a partir de URLs eu achei uma biblioteca desenvolvida por um russo, a *[Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)*, porém esse *slideshow* será utilizado no aplicativo na versão de *tablet*. Na versão para celular eu utilizo uma *listview*.

O único problema é que o *slideshow* estava dando erro na versão 3.0 que é justamente a versão mínima para *tablet*.

Eu faço a conexão com o *webservice* e trago do banco de dados as URLs que mudam constantemente, depois eu utilizo o *pager* e as classes da biblioteca.

```
    String[] imageUrls = new String[logos.size()];//logos é um List<String> que contem as urls
    imageUrls = (String[]) logos.toArray(imageUrls);
    //String[] imageUrls = bundle.getStringArray(Extra.IMAGES);
    int pagerPosition = bundle.getInt(Extra.IMAGE_POSITION, 0);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        pagerPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_POSITION);
    }

    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.stub)
        .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.stub)
        .resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
        .cacheOnDisc(true)
        .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
        .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
        .considerExifParams(true)
        .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300))
        .build();

    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(new ImagePagerAdapter(imageUrls));
    pager.setCurrentItem(pagerPosition);
```

Existe algum outro modo de fazer um *slideshow* ou alguma alternativa, por exemplo, uma *grid* bem estruturada carregando imagens a partir de URLs?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Imagem do erro que esta dando

Comment: Poste o erro pra podermos ajudar. Obs: você pode usar o Universal Image Loader dentro do ListView também.

Comment: Utilizo o UIL em um slide show inclusive no Froyo (2.2) sem problema algum. Poste o erro e poderemos te ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NetworkOnMainThreadException` ocorre quando o app tenta fazer alguma operação de rede na Thread principal (a que roda a interface).

Esta exception foi introduzida no Honeycomb para evitar que ocorram operações demoradas na thread principal que por consequência travaria a interface.

Uma solução rápida é desabilitar o StrictMode (o que gera a Exception):

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy)
```

Mas não recomendo este tipo de abordagem, pois prejudicaria a experiência do usuário e até poderia causar um ANR.

Uma **solução melhor** seria procurar onde que está realizando a operação de rede e colocar esse trecho de código dentro de uma `AsyncTask`. Eu chutaria que o trecho que você pega as informações do webservice seria o causador do problema. Um segundo chute seria dentro do `Adapter` no trecho no qual você carrega a imagem, mas eu acredito que o UniversalImageLoader já faça as operações de rede em uma Thread separada.

Answer (score 0):

No [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) tem exatamente o que você precisa. Dá uma olhada lá. É auto-explicativo.

Comment: Bem-vindo! Mesmo que este link seja uma boa sugestão, esta resposta não terá validade se um dia o link deixar de funcionar. Por isso, e porque é importante para a comunidade ter conteúdo aqui mesmo, seria melhor você responder com respostas mais completas. Você pode elaborar mais sua resposta? Um resumo do conteúdo do link já ajudaria bastante! Saiba mais sobre o assunto neste item do nosso FAQ da Comunidade: [Respostas que apenas contêm links são boas?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/705/respostas-que-apenas-contem-links-sao-boas)